# iAd leaving white space at top and bottom of iAd

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, iad, adbannerview

I just added iAd to one of my apps and it works fine except that it leaves white space at the top and bottom of the banner view. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using storyboard? If so possibly you have set its top constraint to be 8px off the top margin as it will "snap" to that value - the solution would be manually changing the constant of the constraint to 0 or reposition it and update constraints.